# Data profiling in a dataframe based on an input file-pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data file and a rules file. First column of rules file will have columns from the data file and the second column has an pandas operation which has to be performed on the respective Column. Please refer below details:

This is the input data:

```
d={'Name': ['Ankan', 'Shiv', nan, 'Sandeep'], 
'email': ['ankan@domain.com', 'shiv.com', 'something@someting.com', 'sandeep@domain.com'], 
'Street 1': ['Street Name 1', 'Street name 2', 'Street name 3', nan], 
'LastName': [nan, nan, 'LastName1', 'LastName2'], 
'Outlet_Code': ['123abc', nan, 12345, 'bca12']}
df= pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

Which looks like:

```
      Name                   email       Street 1   LastName Outlet_Code
0    Ankan        ankan@domain.com  Street Name 1        NaN      123abc
1     Shiv                shiv.com  Street name 2        NaN         NaN
2      NaN  something@someting.com  Street name 3  LastName1       12345
3  Sandeep      sandeep@domain.com            NaN  LastName2       bca12
```

Now the rules file:

```
d1={'Column_Name': ['Name', 'LastName'], 'Rule': ['.isna()', '.isna()']}
file_rules=pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

---

```
  Column_Name     Rule
0        Name  .isna()
1    LastName  .isna()
```

I am trying to flag the cells in excel where the condition matches per column name. I have a working code which is :

```
m=df.eval([f'{a}{b}' for a,b in zip(file_rules['Column_Name'],file_rules['Rule'])])
cond=pd.DataFrame(m,index=file_rules['Column_Name'].to_numpy()).T
```

---

```
def dummy_color(x):
    c1='background-color:red'
    c2=''
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(cond,c1,c2),columns=x.columns,index=x.index)
    return df1
df.style.apply(dummy_color,axis=None,subset=file_rules.Column_Name)
```

---

Output:
[image]

I want to know if there is any better way of doing this,(since this would be handled by someone else)? Can I do this without `df.eval()`? Kindly suggest.

Comment: How complex can the content of `Rule` be? Are there only a few supported rules, or should it be as free as possible? Can you combine multiple operations?

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for taking a look, the rules can be a regex for example for checking valid email address , also there can be maximum 2 rules combined with an `&` , where both would be pandas standard `str` accessors, except the regex. Please let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: `m`, `c1`, `c2`, `df1`, `dummy_color`, the naming of variables and functions could definitely be improved. You say you have input data in a dictionary, but question mentions you're flagging cells in Excel. I don't see any Excel handling in your question. And what happens when you have multiple rules, will they all get the same colour? I think there's more code and you've left out so much that nobody has dared reviewing it. There's too much missing for a proper review.